# Flutter :how can add other widget under gridview after a certain number of index

Tags: flutter

I am working with flutter gridview project in where i want show another widget after certain number of index.

how can i add widget after each 6 index of gridview

```
GridView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9),),
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),


            itemCount: widget.dicovervehiclelist.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return vehicleview(
                  widget.dicovervehiclelist[index], context,widget.dicovervehiclelist.length,index);
            }),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can put business logic inside itemBuilder.

If the index+1 can be divided by 6, then we put another widget. In this case, I put Text("This is Separator") widget.

```dart
  Widget renderSeparator(){
    return Text("This is Separator");
  }

  Widget renderGrids() {
    Widget grids = GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9),
      ),
      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      // itemCount: widget.dicovervehiclelist.length,
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        // return vehicleview(
        //   widget.dicovervehiclelist[index], 
        //   context,widget.dicovervehiclelist.length,
        //   index);
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Main Content"),
              if ((index+1) % 6 == 0)
                renderSeparator()
            ],
          )
        );
      },
    );
    return grids;
  }
```

**- updated requirement by Hitanshu**

> thanks ...but its only below in that index which is ==5 and so on , i want show below the both index like 4 and 5 ..where crossAxisCount:1

If we want to implement combination of Grid and List View, we need to have

1. CustomScrollView
2. SliverGrid
3. SliverList
4. SliverChildListDelegate

### Working Example App

You may look into repository. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout)

### And this is the full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GridViewListViewIndex extends StatelessWidget {

  final int newsFeedCount = 18;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Special after 6th'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: renderScrollArea(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> businessLogic(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> temp = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < newsFeedCount+1; i++) {
      if (i % 6 == 1) {
        temp.add(renderGrids(context));
      }
      if (i % 6 == 0) {
        temp.add(renderLists(context));
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  Widget renderScrollArea(BuildContext context) {
    final scrollableArea = CustomScrollView(
      slivers: businessLogic(context),

      // Below lines are neglected as we have more complex requirement
      // slivers: <Widget>[
      //   renderGrids(context),
      //   renderLists(context),
      //   renderGrids(context),
      //   renderLists(context),
      // ],
    );
    return scrollableArea;
  }

  Widget renderLists(BuildContext context) {
    final lists = SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          NewsFeed(),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return lists;
  }

  Widget renderGrids(BuildContext context) {
    final grids = SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          NewsFeed(),
          NewsFeed(),
          NewsFeed(),
          NewsFeed(),
          NewsFeed(),
          NewsFeed(),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return grids;
  }
}

class NewsFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white30,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black26,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Content"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Special After 6th]

Comment: thanks ...but its only below in that  index which is ==5 and so on , i want show below the both index like 4 and 5 ..where crossAxisCount:1

Comment: I've updated my answer and add Repo link. You may look at the repo, and I think it's quite convenient to step by step read grid_view_index.dart, then grid_view_list_view.dart and finally grid_view_list_view_index.dart. It's built in steps so we can learn it easily